# How medically accurate is this quote from Person of Interest?

Tags: realism, person-of-interest

In the TV drama Person Of Interest Season 2 Episode 15 (Title: Booked Solid), former CIA agent Reese encounters another agent Hershe and a fight ensues which later leads to a knife fight. Reese manages to get the upper hand and stabs Hershe in what seems to be below the sternum in an upper motion with a large kitchen knife.

He retracts the knife out of Hershe and it shows about a **4 inch
blood smear on the blade.**

> [image]

Following this, Reese then tells Hershe

> Any deeper and I would have cut your celiac artery.
>
> [Pulls knife out]
>
> You've got about 20 minutes before you bleed to death.

Given that he said cut (which I assume means inflicts an injury to the artery wide enough that blood profusely flows out at a high rate), how medically accurate is Reese's statement to Hershe about bleeding out? We don't actually see the blood on Hershe but it shows his struggling to stand up.

Link to the scene below (2:05)

Thanks

Comment: *'Celiac artery, also known as the celiac axis or celiac trunk, is a major visceral artery in the abdominal cavity supplying the foregut. It arises from the abdominal aorta and commonly gives rise to three branches: left gastric artery, splenic artery, and common hepatic artery.'* You've misunderstood. He **didn't** cut the artery. If he *had* cut the celiac artery (a major artery), Hershe would have 'bled out' in less than a minute with arterial spurting. A 'gut wound' that doesn't involve arteries (just organs and/or surrounding tissue) would likely take 20 minutes to bleed out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about real life medicine, not a movie/TV question.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - If that's a valid reason for VTC, then why bother having the [tag:realism] tag? The question is asking whether the TV drama's **depiction** of the event is realistic and that (sadly or not) is a valid question.